# Is there a way to have a stdarray the same size as MPI_Comm_size?

Tags: c++, mpi, stdarray

I have a program where I am trying to gather up a set of data into an std::array however I cannot get this to work when the size of my array is set to the value of the world size. I get the following error:

```
MPITests.cpp:16:21: error: the value of ‘size’ is not usable in a constant expression
   16 |     std::array<int, size> gatheredRanks2;
      |                     ^~~~
```

here is a section of the relevant code:

```
int rank, size;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

std::array<int, size> gatheredRanks2;
```

If I simply set the value of this size to a number the program works.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The size of an `std::array` needs to be a compile time constant. Since you have a runtime value use `std::vector` instead

Comment: The size of an array **must** be known at compile time.